# How to copy the color styling to a color column in a layer's attribute table?

Tags: qgis, leaflet, pyqgis, style

I have a polygon layer in QGIS that I have applied a random color style to each polygon. Under Layer Properties -> Style I selected a Categorized style and then generated a random color ramp. I added a color column to the layer table. Is there a way to automatically copy the color assigned in the style to the color column for each polygon in the form "#ff0000".

Ultimately, I want to export it as a GeoJSON layer and import it into a leaflet map. The color column will set the color in leaflet.

Answer (score 26):

You could use PyQGIS for that (not sure is the best solution for it, though).

Assuming your layer has a `color` field (type: string), select (or activate) the layer in the QGIS ToC, open the QGIS Python console, and copy this code snippet:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
attr = layer.renderer().classAttribute()
attrColor = 'color'  # Name of the field to store colors
fieldIndex = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex(attrColor)
attrFeatMap = {}

for cat in layer.renderer().categories(): 
    expr = "\"" + attr + "\"='" + unicode(cat.value()) + "'"

    for f in layer.getFeatures(expr):
        attrMap = {fieldIndex : cat.symbol().color().name()}
        attrFeatMap[f.id()] = attrMap
  
layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues( attrFeatMap )
```

After running it, you'll obtain this:

[image]

Let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: Is there possibilite to do it for RGB?

Comment: Sure. Instead of calling `cat.symbol().color().name()`, do something like this: `str(cat.symbol().color().red()) +','+ str(cat.symbol().color().green()) +','+ str(cat.symbol().color().blue())`

Comment: Still valid in qgis 3.6, apart from the API rename rendererV2 -> renderer

Comment: Didn't worked on QGis 3.6 here. I've renamed rendererV2 to renderer, but didn't worked.

Comment: @Paladini, just updated the answer to work with QGIS v3.x (tested on QGIS 3.16).

Comment: v.3.26. Not work :(

Comment: Could neither get it to work under 3.26.3. Had to adjust the indents, so the code runs, but it doesn't write anything to the attribute table. To me, as a Python-noob, it seems like attrFeatMap is not populated... the last two lines are like `layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues( attrFeatMap )
True
attrFeatMap
{}`