# How to save color VALUE to attribute table in QGIS for a vector layer with a graduated symbol renderer

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, fields-attributes, vector-grid

I am trying to achieve this -> [How to copy the color styling to a color column in a layer's attribute table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82892/how-to-copy-the-color-styling-to-a-color-column-in-a-layers-attribute-table)

script by @Germán Carrillo

```
prefix = "'"
layer = iface.activeLayer()
attr = layer.rendererV2().classAttribute()
attrColor = 'color' # Name of the field to store colors
fieldIndex = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex(attrColor)
attrFeatMap = {}

for cat in layer.rendererV2().categories(): 
  expr = "\""+attr+"\"="+prefix+unicode(cat.value())+prefix
  for f in layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(QgsExpression(expr))):
    attrMap = { fieldIndex : cat.symbol().color().name()}
    attrFeatMap[ f.id() ] = attrMap

layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues( attrFeatMap )
```

but after using that script I am getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2' object has no attribute 'categories'
```

because it is for a layer classified with a Categorized Symbol Renderer.

So problem is that I can use this script only with random color... 
But how to make same thing gradient colors like ndvi -1 / 1

could this help me? -> http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#graduated-symbol-renderer

First time working with python.....

**EDIT:** Qgis 2.10.1 - PISA
**EDIT:** Iam adding picture

[image]

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: @ArMoraer Qgis 2.10.1 - PISA

Comment: The issue is that the renderer class is **QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2** instead of **QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2**. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the renderer class is **QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2** instead of **QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2**. So, I categorized next shapefile  by FID field:

[image]

and identical code (Germán Carrillo' script ) was run at the Python Console of QGIS:

```
prefix = "'"
layer = iface.activeLayer()
attr = layer.rendererV2().classAttribute()
attrColor = 'color' # Name of the field to store colors
fieldIndex = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex(attrColor)
attrFeatMap = {}

for cat in layer.rendererV2().categories(): 
  expr = "\""+attr+"\"="+prefix+unicode(cat.value())+prefix
  for f in layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(QgsExpression(expr))):
    attrMap = { fieldIndex : cat.symbol().color().name()}
    attrFeatMap[ f.id() ] = attrMap

layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues( attrFeatMap )
```

As you can see at the next image, result was completely satisfactory (I am not getting any error):

[image]

**Editing Note:**

This is the code for Graduated Symbol Renderer:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

provider = layer.dataProvider()

renderer = layer.rendererV2()

feats = [ feat for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]
values = [ feat.attribute('FID')  for feat in feats ] #change for 'NDVI' in case of NDVI field

n = len(feats)

color_feats = [ renderer.symbolForValue(value).color().name() for value in values ]

idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('color')

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    new_values = {idx : color_feats[i]}
    provider.changeAttributeValues({i:new_values})
```

After running it at the Python Console of QGIS, values at 'color' field were placed as expected.

[image]

By using 'NDVI' field it also works perfectly:

[image]

Comment: I cant use Categorized I really need graduated. I have edited question and added picture

Answer (score 1):

OK I have answer

here is plugin made by [@underdark](https://jcastellssala.com/2014/05/12/color-to-attribute-qgis-2-x/)

and here is it on [GitHub](https://github.com/kxtells/kxtells_qgis_plugins/tree/qgis2.2)

Working fine!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for a graduated render:

```py
prefix = "'"
layer = iface.activeLayer()
attr = layer.rendererV2().classAttribute()
attrColor = 'color' # Name of the field to store colors
fieldIndex = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex(attrColor)
attrFeatMap = {}

for cat in layer.rendererV2().ranges():
    expr = "\""+attr+"\">="+prefix+unicode(cat.lowerValue())+prefix+'AND'+"\""+attr+"\"<="+prefix+unicode(cat.upperValue())+prefix
    for f in layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(QgsExpression(expr))):
        attrMap = { fieldIndex : cat.symbol().color().name()}
        attrFeatMap[ f.id() ] = attrMap
layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues( attrFeatMap )
```

The only difference with your code is the using of the `ranges()` method instead of `categories()` and the slight editing of the `expr` expression because this time you don't deal with a single value, but with a whole range of values.

Comment: your code give this error
<pre>File "<input>", line 6
    layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues( attrFeatMap )
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax<code>

have look on my answer there is plugin made by underdark which is working fine

Comment: It worked for me, I tried to copy&paste it again.

Comment: Your code is wrong. It doesn't work when number of classes is lesser than features number. **QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2** class has different methods compared to **QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2** and for this reason an algorithm similar to Germán Carrillo' script doesn't work. You can see my **Editing Note**.

Comment: @xunilk I have accepted your answer

Comment: @xunilk I didn't widely tested it, but it worked for my sample dataset... Thanks for the clarification, I'll do some research about that!

Comment: @ABCD Thanks. However, I found out one inconsistency in my code. It only worked for FIDs. New version (I edited my answer) works for any field. If you classified, e.g, by NDVI field you need to change 'FID' label for 'NDVI' in values list.

Comment: @mgri You're welcome. However, my code only worked for FIDs. I newly modified my code for including whatever field.