# Can ArcGIS Desktop read label properties in geopackages created in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, labeling, geopackage

Can ArcGIS Desktop read the labels, including the label placement and label formatting, in geopackages created in QGIS?

Comment: What happened when you ran tests to try and answer your question?  Were the geopackages read using ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: The answer to those questions would also be interesting to know for me. I don’t have a ArcGIS license, so I can not try. But my clients run ArcGIS, so it’s important to know, if they can use GPKG at all of the layer symbology stored in the GPKG. To make it short: It would be good to know, in which format to send data to ArcGIS users.

Comment: I don't have ArcGIS so I can't do tests

Comment: There are no standardized method for storing styles into GeoPackage yet. ArcGIS does not read the QGIS styles from the layer_styles table. Data transfers naturally accurately but styles not at all. I believe that is the case for any other format as well.

Comment: Since ArcGIS can't read/use the QGIS styles I wondered about storing symbology and label styles to the attribute table with the hope ArcGIS could use those values in creating its symbols.  I haven't found much but here's an example of people coming up with some code to do this with colors.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82892/how-to-copy-the-color-styling-to-a-color-column-in-a-layers-attribute-table and for gradients https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231505/how-to-save-color-value-to-attribute-table-in-qgis-for-a-vector-layer-with-a-gra